# NInject Custom context

Tags: ninject

I'll expose what I'm doing now, and later, what I'd like to do using NInject.

Classes:

1. Kernel,
2. ApiClient
3. IIdentity

Kernel exposes several methods as:

```
object method(IIdentity identity)
-----------------------
public List<Domain.Channel> getChannels(Domain.Identity.IIdentity identity) {...}
```

Kernel contains several identities stored, and according each context I need to do a thing or another.
In this case, my context is inside the method and the context key is identity parameter value. According this one, I need to get an instance of ApiClient.

Actually, I'm doing this using a Dictionary property of Kernel class:

```
 private Dictionary<Domain.Identity.IIdentity, LEST.Client.ApiClient> lests;
```

And then I initialize.

```
 foreach (Domain.Identity.IIdentity identity in this.identities)
 {
     LEST.Client.ApiClient lest = new LEST.Client.ApiClient();
     lest.configure(identity.ClientId, identity.Username, identity.Password);

     this.lests.Add(identity, lest);
 }
```

So, when I need to get a concrete ApiClient object according an identity:

```
public List<Domain.Channel> getChannels(Domain.Identity.IIdentity identity)
{
    LEST.Client.ApiClient current_lest;
    this.lests.TryGetValue(identity, out current_lest);

    if (current_lest != null)
    {
        ...        
    }
```

I'd like to do it using NInject. I've created a module in order to create the bindings to itselfs. The problem is that I've no idea how to create a custom context like this.

I'll appreciate a lot your help.

Thanks for all.

**EDIT**

I've abstracted a basic Core class that summarizes my explanation.

```
public class Core
{
    private IList<IIdentity> identities;
    private Ninject.IKernel kernel;

    public Core()
    {
        this.identities = new List<IIdentity>();
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        this.kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel(new LestModule());
    }

    public void openSession(IIdentity identity)
    {
        ApiClient client = this.kernel.Get<ApiClient>();
    }

    public void doSomething(IIdentity identity)
    {
        ApiClient client = this.kernel.Get<ApiClient>();
        client...
    }

    public void closeSession(IIdentity identity)
    {
        ApiClient client = this.kernel.Get<ApiClient>();
        this.kernel.Release(client);
    }
}
```

And the module is:

```
public class LestModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<ApiClient>().ToProvider(new CustomProvider());
        this.Bind<IIdentity>().To<Identity>();
    }
}

public class CustomProvider : IProvider<ApiClient>
{

    public object Create(IContext context)
    {
        //context data???
        // How to obtain current IIdentity on here?
        object d = context;
        return new ApiClient("", "", "");
    }

    public System.Type Type
    {
        get { return typeof(ApiClient); }
    }
}
```

And the abstraction of ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient
{

    private string username;

    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }

    private string client_id;

    public string ClientId
    {
        get { return client_id; }
        set { client_id = value; }
    }

    private string passwd;

    public string Passwd
    {
        get { return passwd; }
        set { passwd = value; }
    }


    public ApiClient(string client_id, string username, string password)
    {
        this.client_id = client_id;
        this.username = username;
        this.passwd = password;
    }
}
```

So, I'd like that:

1. In openSession: Create a ApiClient instance (this.kernel.Get) initializing the instance according the IIdentity param of this method.
2. In doSomething: Get a ApiClient instance according the IIdentity param of this method.
3. In closeSession: Realise the instance according the IIdentity param of this method.

Comment: Is the initialization of the dictionary done once per application or once per user/session? If it's the first, you can bind them with an identifier (either named binding or custom binding with custom token/parameter). If it's the second, then you can put the dictionary + logic into an `IProvider` and bind this.

Comment: Thanks @BatteryBackupUnit. Once per user/session. I've provided a example implementation of each classes on post. Please, I've not quite figured out how to carry out this IProvider implementation. Could you help me a bit please?

Comment: From the information given in the post it seems more like the identity dictionary is initialized once per application not per session/user. From the looks of it, if it's once per session/user i would not use the DI container to implement it. If it's once per application you can do it using the container, but it may be that there's no benefit in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this.

It's working now.

```
public class LestModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{

    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<LEST.Client.ApiClient>().ToProvider<LEST.Client.ApiClient>(new ApiClientProvider());
    }

}

public class ApiClientProvider : Ninject.Activation.IProvider<LEST.Client.ApiClient>
{

    private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Domain.Identity.LESTIdentity, LEST.Client.ApiClient> lests;

    public ApiClientProvider()
    {
        this.lests = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Domain.Identity.LESTIdentity, LEST.Client.ApiClient>();
    }

    public object Create(Ninject.Activation.IContext context)
    {
        Ninject.Parameters.IParameter identity_parameter = context.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "identity");
        Domain.Identity.LESTIdentity identity = (Domain.Identity.LESTIdentity)identity_parameter.GetValue(context, null);

        LEST.Client.ApiClient current_client = null;
        this.lests.TryGetValue(identity, out current_client);
        if (current_client == null)
        {
            current_client = new LEST.Client.ApiClient();
            current_client.configure(...);

            this.lests.Add(identity, current_client);
        }

        return current_client;
    }

    ...
}
```

In order to get the instance according to the identity:

```
public void createChannel(Domain.Identity.ClientIdentity client_identity, Domain.Identity.UserIdentity user_identity, Domain.Channel channel)
    {
        LEST.Client.ApiClient client = NinjectServiceLocator.Instance.Kernel.Get<LEST.Client.ApiClient>(new Ninject.Parameters.Parameter("identity", new Domain.Identity.LESTIdentity(user_identity.Id, user_identity.Name, client_identity.Id, client_identity.Name), true));
        client.ChannelsApiP.Create(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Domain.Channel, LEST.Model.ChannelDTO>(channel));
    }
```

What do you thing about?

Comment: how will you ever remove an entry from `this.lests` - or is this not needed?